# audio Filtering android

Tags: android, audio

is there a way to filter audio in android system?
I am interested to get only the audio of a fixed frequency.

Answer (score 2):

If you get your audio via the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class, then you'll have raw audio data that you could filter using whatever audio filter algorithm you have. Or are you looking for an audio filtering library?

Comment: I'm not a Android specialist, but I'd also add that it's unlikely that Android itself would have such an specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This is the approach I used. I get audio with AudioRecord class and then I used different algorithms in order to manipulate the audio

Comment: can you please provide more details i want to do similar task.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave says, the AudioRecord class is the easiest way.  Often times, I will extend an AsyncTask that implements AudioRecord to read the audio buffer and push the buffer back to the UI thread for visualization (if needed).

Regarding the filtering of the audio, Android does not provide any built-in way of doing this.  The way you would filter out certain frequencies is by taking the Fourier Transform of the sampled audio and then pulling out the frequencies of interest.

If you want more details on filtering, you should probably post a new SO question or wiki the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).  You might also look into [JTransforms](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtransforms/) which is a great open source FFT library that runs wonderfully on Android.

Comment: can you please help me out I want to filter range of frequency from raw data returned by Audiorecord using JTransforms how can i do that any good example or tutorial appriciate d?

Answer (score 2):

Please [do NOT use the FFT for this](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/when-to-not-use-fft.html). That's amateur hour. (The FFT is a great tool with many great use-cases, but this is not one of them.) You most likely want to solve this problem using time domain filters. [Here's a post](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html) to get you started writing your own filters in the time domain as easy as can be. However, a lot of people stumble on that since it's a bit specialized, so if you want to use something built-in to android, start with the [equalizer audio effect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html).